# git merge Issues Branch with different folder structure

Tags: git, merge

Am facing some issues in merging git branches.
My problem is as below I have a master branch with folder structure src> views> a.js....

I have created another branch A from the master and modified the folder structure to WWW > Views> a.js.....  but I didn't push the commits to master

Also I have another branch named B which has some unique feautres(about 15 commits) which are not available in the master branch.

In this branch also I have manually modified the folder structure to WWW > Views> a.js.....  but I didn't push the commits to master branch

Now I need to merge the branches A and B. While merging those branches am getting the below error

#### CONFLICT (rename/delete):

```
www/views/a.js deleted in HEAD and renamed in B.
```

Version B of www/views/a.js left in tree.

Then how about to go with merge strategies with branch A and B?

Comment: Have you first committed all your changes before the merge?

Comment: Yes, else git would complain about local changes will get overwritten by merge or similar error

Answer (score 0):

-->revert the commit in B with changes to  `WWW > Views> a.js.....` (or use rebase -i to remove those changes)
-->now merge, all will be well

If this dosen't work then merge, resolve the conflict anyway, then manually put the version of a.js you want on master and commit